# How to set language to english in a SSIS-Package temporarily?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How I can set language to english in a SSIS-Job? I need it temporarily to get english date formats (e.g. '01 Oct 2015') correctly interpreted as date.

Comment: That's the wrong way to go about it. The correct way is to specify the correct locale or format in whatever step you read the data, eg in a Flat File Source, or parse the data with a Script transformation

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I changed the locale in the data flow task both in source and destination, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: each element in an SSIS package has a **LocaleID** field in properties, under Misc. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: yes, I set it from german to english(US)

Comment: In the Data Flow, under Advanced settings for the Flat File Source (right click on it), in the ... input buffers I think, find your source column. Change the FastParse option from False to True. This will take out locale aware parsing which conveniently enough for you, should default to 'Murican parsing rules